# Does potassium hydroxide etch steel?

Tags: experimental-physics

Potassium hydroxide is a good etching agent for glasses. If the sample is laser processed, then the etching rate is much more faster.
I want to use stainless steel (because of its good thermal conductivity) as a vessel which will contain the KOH solution with the laser processed samples. I have to maintain the temperature of KOH at 85 degree celsius while the sample is getting sonicated at ultrasonic frequency for faster etching.
Is steel vessel is what I should opt for for the above mentioned etching process. Or are there better options?

Answer (score 0):

In general, iron-based alloys do not corrode in alkaline solutions- in fact, buffering the solution into alkalinity is one of the most common ways of preventing iron or steel from corroding. There are always exceptions- in particular, if chloride is present as a contaminant, then even stainless steel will be subject to pitting corrosion unless it is specifically alloyed to resist pitting in the presence of chloride ions.

A corrosion handbook will tell you which type of stainless to use on your application.